# Markdown previewer

Tags: javascript, python, markdown

I'm using Python markdown with Django. It works perfectly. But static HTML previewer it is not enough for an admin panel. I can't find any dynamic JS markdown previewer (I don't need a full converter). Please, advise a javascript markdown previewer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably looking for [`showdown.js`](http://softwaremaniacs.org/playground/showdown-highlight/)

Here's an article about it: [Using Showdown with and without jQuery](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/showdown-javascript-jquery)

It boils down to this:

```
var converter = new Showdown.converter();
var input = $("textarea");
var preview = $("#preview");
$(input).keyup(function() {
    preview.html(converter.makeHtml(input.val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As another approach, you can use the free API provided in this page:

https://helloacm.com/markdown/

```
https://helloacm.com/api/markdown/?cached&s=Markdown rocks!
```

It will return JSON-encoded data:

```
"<p>Markdown rocks!<\/p>"
```